# msaccess sql select sort on secondary select

Tags: sql, sorting, ms-access, ms-access-2003

MSAccess 2003

I have an SQL query such as the following:

```
Select ID, 
    (Select Count(*) 
     from TableB 
     Where TableB.ID=TableA.ID) as TableBID 
From TableA
Order By 2 Asc
```

That "Order By 2" doesn't produce an error - but it sure doesn't sort based on the value of "Count(*)" returned by the sub-query (or secondary Select).

What do I need to do in order to sort based on the value of "Count(*)" returned?

As a secondary question, why can't I use the name of "TableBID" in the Order By expression instead of the number "2"?

Comment: Sorry HansUp - I was writing from memory first thing this morning. I corrected my query (which is of course the basics of the query broken down for example) - and it looks like your first one below. That does NOT work. It does not sort on columns 2.

Comment: I tried your second query example, and it does work. However, it takes much longer to complete. Why wouldn't the first query example, like mine, work? Why can't I sort on "TableBID" as the name instead of having to use the Ordinal number of "2"? Thanks.

Comment: Hi HansUp. Thanks for your help. Each of the ID fields is indexed. However, in order to simplify the issue for these purposes, I have broken the query down into its basic form. TableA is really a complex saved query with multiple joins. The query works instantly with my format above, and takes about 30X as long with your format below. In its simplified form, as shown above, it still doesn't work. Why is that? I guess the answer doesn't matter - we know it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is wrap your SQL statement with an outer SQL statement for sorting.

```
Select * from (
    Select ID, 
       (Select Count(*) 
        from TableB 
        Where TableB.ID=TableA.ID) as TableBID 
    From Table
) as tblwrapper
Order By TableBID Asc
```